# check the variable have no count

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel I have send the ajax response to the controller. there I have check the condition to check the count of the response geo as `if(count($request['geo']))` and for some reason I want to check the condition if no count for geo as    `if(count($request['geo']) == 0)`.but its not working.
How to check the condition 'if no count for geo' in laravel

Comment: the code you've written, `if(count($request['geo']) == 0)` should work please show the full code :)

Comment: `if(count($request['geo']) === 0 )` use `===`

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist that's usually good advice, however count() always returns an integer, so in this case it does not matter :)

Comment: Though it is ajax response, so I think it should be `if(count($request['geo']) == null)` or `if(count($request['geo']) === null)`

Comment: I suggest to dd your request to see what exactly it contains. `dd($request()->all());` Then I/we can suggest from there.

Comment: "_I have send the ajax response to the controller_" You mean a request? You send a _request_ to the controller, the controller in return sends a _response_. Make sure your request contains `geo` by using `dd($request)`. You can also use `if($request->has('geo')...`. Is `$request` even an array??

Answer (score 0):

if `$request['geo']` contains an array, then `count($request['geo']) == 0` will be `true` for empty array `[]`.

But if `$request['geo']` contains a string (e.g. `'[]'`) - it won't work and you can't use `count()` for strings. For checking empty strings you can use `$request['geo'] == ''` or `!$request['geo']`

Probably you need to check the type of value first, e.g. using `is_array($request['geo'])`

P.S. `!$request['geo']` works for both - empty arrays and empty strings

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this

```
if(empty($request['geo'])){
 // your code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use php function gettype and count.
So you can use following code:

```
if(gettype($request['geo']) == 'array') {
    if (count($request['geo']) == 0) {
        // your code here
    } else { // count > 0
       // your other code here
    }
}
```

Hope to helpful.